# Google Photos desktop backup uploader and mapped network SMB shares

Tags: windows, macos, google-photos

I've got a network drive mapped/mounted on both OS X and Windows 8.x.

The respective [Google Photos desktop uploaders](https://photos.google.com/apps) are configured to read that drive, and indeed recognizes the files on the mounted directory.

The problem is that the uploader doesn't seem to actually upload those files. The count stays the same. This behaviour occurs on both operating systems for the same source mounted drive.

Does Google Photos Backup for OS X and Windows actually back up photos on network drives?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me as well. It recognized all the network drive photos (50,000) + local drives (500). Uploaded the local photos and then decided it was done. Once it was done the local photos, the number of photos recognized went down to 0. I left it running for half a day to see if it would recover.

What worked for me was exiting (right-click --> exit in Windows) the app entirely (which ended up being for a few hours) then restarting it. The app took a while in a "looking for photos" status, then saw there was still 50k photos to upload and commenced.